# SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION has no effect

Tags: android, layout, fullscreen

I'm using this code inside a `VideoView` to try to hide the navigation bar on a Touchpad running Android (CyanogenMod) 4.1.

```
    setSystemUiVisibility(SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

Unfortunately it has no effect at all, and gives no error. I am at a loss what to look for (and I appreciate that "it doesn't work" isn't very helpful, but I am under the impression that that is the only line of code you need to use, and since there are no errors...)

I've tried various variations - `getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVi...`, doing it in multiple places, on a timer, etc. That line of code is definitely reached but it simply doesn't do anything.

Comment: Try `setSystemUiVisibility(SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);`

Comment: No effect; I've tried most combinations.

Comment: I think you marked the duplicates the wrong way around, but no big deal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oh how ridiculous. After reading the source code - which is often the only way to find things out in Android-land - I discovered the following undocumented fact:

**setSystemUiVisibility() only has effect when the view you call it from is visible!**

Even more: The view in which you call setSystemUiVisibility() must *remain* visible for the nav bar to remain hidden. Thanks for documenting that guys, really great.

Here is the relevant code, in [`View.java`](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/View.java).

```
void performCollectViewAttributes(AttachInfo attachInfo, int visibility) {
    if ((visibility & VISIBILITY_MASK) == VISIBLE) {
        if ((mViewFlags & KEEP_SCREEN_ON) == KEEP_SCREEN_ON) {
            attachInfo.mKeepScreenOn = true;
        }
        attachInfo.mSystemUiVisibility |= mSystemUiVisibility;
        ListenerInfo li = mListenerInfo;
        if (li != null && li.mOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener != null) {
            attachInfo.mHasSystemUiListeners = true;
        }
    }
}
```