# setSystemUiVisibility(SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION) does not work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fullscreen

I've been battling with setSystemUiVisibility() to try to hide the soft navigation buttons for a while (for a video player). It does not seem to work as advertised. Here is my code, inside a visible `FrameLayout`.

```
void setNavVisibility(boolean visible)
{
    int newVis = SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN;
    if (!visible)
    {
        newVis |= SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
    }
    setSystemUiVisibility(newVis);
}
```

Slightly modified from the SDK example:

```
    void setNavVisibility(boolean visible) {
        int newVis = SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE;
        if (!visible) {
            newVis |= SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
        }
```

Neither do anything when called. I had some success when I called them from a different `View`, but the documentation doesn't mention that the `View` you are calling from has any effect? I assume that the documentation is (surprise surprise) somewhat lacking here. Does anyone know what's really going on?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Hmm apparently I [duplicated my own question!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887278/system-ui-flag-layout-hide-navigation-has-no-effect) But anyway I found the answer: After reading the source code - which is often the only way to find things out in Android-land - I discovered the following undocumented fact:

**setSystemUiVisibility() only has effect when the view you call it from is visible!**

Even more: The view in which you call setSystemUiVisibility() must *remain* visible for the nav bar to remain hidden. Thanks for documenting that guys, really great.

Here is the relevant code, in `View.java`.

```
void performCollectViewAttributes(AttachInfo attachInfo, int visibility) {
    if ((visibility & VISIBILITY_MASK) == VISIBLE) {
        if ((mViewFlags & KEEP_SCREEN_ON) == KEEP_SCREEN_ON) {
            attachInfo.mKeepScreenOn = true;
        }
        attachInfo.mSystemUiVisibility |= mSystemUiVisibility;
        ListenerInfo li = mListenerInfo;
        if (li != null && li.mOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener != null) {
            attachInfo.mHasSystemUiListeners = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good work! That condition unfortunately makes way for really annoying bugs.

Comment: Can you say how you solved this? When would be a good time to call ```setSystemUiVisibility``` then?

Comment: Just use an empty `View` somewhere in your layout that is always visible.

Comment: @Timmmm But what's with the bottom gap that happens when the navigation bar disappear, the activity layout doesn't extend itself even after using requestLayout

Comment: How to reset to default values (flags), show navigation bar again?

Comment: What is AttachInfo.?

Comment: Some internal implementation detail; you don't really need to know. (You can look in the source if you are interested though.)

Answer (score 7):

I use setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() to make this full screen mode work for me including hiding the navigation bar.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(
                new OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                        if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                            getActionBar().show();
                        } else {
                            int mUIFlag = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
                            getWindow().getDecorView()
                                    .setSystemUiVisibility(mUIFlag);
                            getActionBar().hide();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    super.onResume();
}
```

it seems that android only trigger the setSystemUiVisibility() when inside the listener.

Answer (score 6):

I implemented this as below however I get a blank gap at the bottom (see screenshot)

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            );
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should probably post this as another question rather than an answer (which it isn't).

Comment: That would be a duplicate :)

Comment: This is on a device that has the (Nexus / Pixel) a soft navigation bar (back, home etc) you need to take that into account.

Comment: @GolanShay What do you mean by take than into account? How to get my activity to full the screen when I get the nav bar to be hidden?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure no user interaction is going on? i.e. emulating a touch which causes the controls to instantly reappear?

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION):

> `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION`: There is a limitation: because navigation controls are so important, the least user interaction will cause them to reappear immediately. When this happens, both this flag and `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN` will be cleared automatically, so that both elements reappear at the same time.

On a side note, I've noticed issues with the view not resizing under some circumstances even with the stock video player in JB. I think it's (or was) a bug.

Comment: Fairly sure from looking at the code. Is there a better way to tell?

Comment: @Oleg I get the navigation bar to disappear, but the problem that it leaves a gap in its place and the activity doesn't extend to the bottom of the screen even if I used requestLayout, this is my question in details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52915745/requestlayout-doesnt-reflect-the-change-after-using-system-ui-flag-hide-navigat

Answer (score 0):

I found that if the user interacted with the device then the navigation bar would return.
Immediately setting the flags in the `OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener` handler method would not work. It would work if you changed them after a one second delay.

```
protected static final int requiredDecorViewFlags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;


protected void listenToUiVisibilityChange() {
    Window window = getWindow();
    if(window == null) {
        return;
    }
    final View view = window.getDecorView();
    if(view == null) {
        return;
    }
    view.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(
        new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                Handler handler = new Handler(
                    getMainLooper()
                );
                handler.postDelayed(
                    new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Window activityWindow = getWindow();
                            if(activityWindow == null) {
                                return;
                            }
                            View decorView = activityWindow.getDecorView();
                            if(decorView == null) {
                                return;
                            }
                            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(requiredDecorViewFlags);
                       }
                   },
                   1000
               );
           }
       }
    );
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    listenToUiVisibilityChange();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//do it by the following method hide it the status bar in sdk < 19 and for 
// greater u can do by providing the by the following i am doing here for both



      public void FullScreencall() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(8);
     }
    else {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility
     (InputDeviceCompat.SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN);
     }
   }
```