# Different behavior between ICS and Jelly Bean when using Window's FLAG_FULLSCREEN

Tags: java, android, view, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I need to show a `DialogFragment` on top of an existing normal `Activity` (non fullscreen and with `ActionBar` visible).
My `DialogFragment` needs to be in fullscreen, so I'm using the following lines to achieve that result:

```java
getDialog().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
getDialog().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR);
```

On ICS everything works fine, my `DialogFragment` is shown in fullscreen and when I close it my `Activity` content haven't been resized so there is no layout glitches (as it should since the fullscreen flag I'm setting should affect only the window where the `DialogFragment` resides).

On Jelly Bean instead when I close my `DialogFragment` I see that my `Activity` content was resized to cover also the statusbar and so there is a layout glitch when it tries to return to the original size.
I think this may be related to the introduction of the new system UI flags (`SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN`, etc) but I couldn't figure out how to have the same ICS behavior also on Jelly Bean... Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a workaround, you need to call:

```java
view.setFitsSystemWindows(true);
```

before setting the fullscreen flag to your window, and in the same way:

```java
view.setFitsSystemWindows(false);
```

before clearing it.

`view` must be a View inside your `Activity` (not your `DialogFragment`!) and it must be visible (see [setSystemUiVisibility(SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION) does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178237/setsystemuivisibilitysystem-ui-flag-layout-hide-navigation-does-not-work))

Still, there are some glitches when animating the dismiss of the `DialogFragment` that are not present on ICS... But I think that's another issue...