# Hidden Navigation Bar still occupies space

Tags: android

I'm using immersive full screen mode. The Action and Navigation bar are hidden, still, the navigation bar ocupies place in the screen.

[image]

That black space it's exactly the space of the nav bar. My layout never draw over that space... What can I do?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
}
```

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14184046/5923606

Comment: Did you resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 8):

Look in your `activity_main.xml` for

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

If you find, remove it or set `false`

Comment: I have been searching for this for hours, I have tried all possible solutions on the net I could find, none of them worked. This was the last solution after which I would give up. Thanks a lot man, this looks so simple I would never say it works

Comment: what if I need for status fit only but not navigation?