# requestLayout doesn't reflect the change after using SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using the following code / flags to hide the bottom navigation bar, but the problem is that my activity views doesn't redraw / refresh / re-layout itself to reflect this change.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
   int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
   View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
   decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
}

RootRelativeLayout.requestLayout();
```

My activity code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_relativelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:clipToPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The inner RelativeLayout stays in its place as if the navigation bar still exist and don't drop to the bottom of the screen even though I called requestLayout() on its parent RelativeLayout.

As you see in the picture there's a gab at the bottom
[image]

I found a solution to this problem but it also cause another problem.

The solution I came to is to set android:fitsSystemWindows to be false instead of true.

But it causes a problem, that my activity's aligned-top views go behind the status bar, the only solution in my mind is to set top padding to the height of the status bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future searchers the solution is to set fitsSystemWindows to be false.

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
```

Comment: On using `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` What did you do to solve this?   _But it causes a problem, that my activity's aligned-top views go behind the status bar, the only solution in my mind is to set top padding to the height of the status bar._

Answer (score 0):

this occurs when you have too many full-screen flags passed to setSystemUiVisibility. With this combo I did not observe the problem:

myRelativeLayout.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);

when I did have the problem, android:fitsSystemWindows="false" did not fix it.